# How to install openfwwf firmware with b43 driver on openwrt?

Tags: wireless-router, openwrt

I have modified Openfwwf firmware (Asm codes). Now I want to install the firmware for the b43 driver on Linksyswrt54GL which runs openwrt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compile the firmware with b43-asm and once you have the .fw files simply replace them in /lib/firmware/b43

Comment: do you have any idea how to read the shared memory of openfwwf and send it to the laptop.